# MimeBodyPart not set encoding UTF-8 for Asian languages

Tags: java, utf-8, io, jakarta-mail, mime-message

When I am receiving mail I am getting question mark for all the characters. I am confused where I am getting wrong. There are attachmnets which are displaying correctly only the charcters are getting displayed `????` like question mark. I have verified the body is correctly getting converted to all the asian language but before sending a mail when I again verified the message they were displaying `??`.

```
  public void addAttachmentsforMail(String text, MimeMessage message, List<File> attachments, MimeSubtype mimeSubtype) throws MessagingException {

    MimeBodyPart mbpText = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbpText.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=utf-8");

//I have verified till here the body is getting converted to respective asian languages
    if(mimeSubtype.equals(MimeSubtype.HTML)) {
                   mbpText.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body, "text/html")));        

            }

            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            mp.addBodyPart(mbpText);        

            MimeBodyPart mimeAttachment;
            for (File file : attachment) {

                mbpAttachment =  new MimeBodyPart();

                FileDataSource foo = new FileDataSource(file);
                mimeAttachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(foo));
                mimeAttachment.setHeader("Content-ID","<" + foo.getName() + ">");
                mimeAttachment.setFileName(foo.getName());

                mp.addBodyPart(mimeAttachment);


            }

   //But When I verify the message in log at here before sending the mail all the charcters were converted in to ???         

 message.setContent(mp);

transport.send(message)
        }
```

This is the header of the mail

```
Message-ID: <-1251496143.10677.1468164058574.JavaMail.star@gmail.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?5biQ5oi35Y+K5a+G56CB5o+Q6YaS?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_10649_-1456564573.1468164040753"

------=_Part_10649_-1456564573.1468164040753
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mbpText.setHeader call is having no effect because of the following mbpText.setDataHandler.  If possible, use the setText methods that allow you to specify a charset.  You might also want to set the System property "mail.mime.charset" to "utf-8".

Comment: ?UTF-8?B?.... I am getting this as my subject.I am using message.setSubject(body, charset);. I have debug and at this point the body is dislpaying correct chinese character and charset is UTF-8 but at the mail  why it is displaying something like this as a  subject ?UTF-8?B?.

Comment: Now I am getting blank body   when I am changing data handler application\octastream .I am getting an attached html  where all the translations are in chinese.So again when i changed the data handler to  part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), "text/html")));
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
 boundary="----=_Part_27_-1687030402.1468221528071"

------=_Part_27_-1687030402.1468221528071
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: The subject is being encoded because it has non-ASCII characters; the "=?UTF-8?..." is the encoded text.  It will be decoded by the mailer before displaying it.  For the body, if you have the data in a String, use the setText method, not the very complicated setDataHandler call that you're using.  If the data is coming from a file, use the attachFile method, but you need to know what charset encoding was used in the file and include that in the contentType argument to the method.